# My messages don't get sent in PHP MaIler

Tags: php, phpmailer

I'm making a response email to someone that fills out a form on my website, the email to the admin of the website, containing all the details of the registrations goes successfully.

However, the email to the person that filled the form doesn't go.
$emailres contains the email address of the person that fills the form, and it works fine.

```
<?php

require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';
require 'class.phpmailer.php';

$emailres = filter_var(trim($_POST["trilogy_email"]), FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
$email_content_res = "Response";



$mailcon = new PHPMailer(); // create a new object
$mailcon->IsSMTP(); // enable SMTP
$mailcon->SMTPDebug =0; // debugging: 1 = errors and messages, 2 = messages only
$mailcon->SMTPAuth = true; // authentication enabled
$mailcon->SMTPSecure = 'tls'; // secure transfer enabled REQUIRED for GMail
$mailcon->Host = "###";
$mailcon->Port = 25; // or 587
$mailcon->IsHTML(true);
$mailcon->Username = "###";
$mailcon->Password = "###";
$mailcon->SetFrom("abc@example.com");
$mailcon->Subject = "Thank you for booking an event";
$mailcon->Body = "$email_content_res";
$mailcon->AddReplyTo("abc@example.com","abc Reservations");
$mailcon->AddAddress($emailres);
$mailcon->Send();


?>
```

If I add an email address, such as $emailres="abc@example.com", the email gets delivered just fine. 
If I accept the address from the HTML form the email doesn't get sent.

Comment: Well, `var_dump($emailres)` is probably not your email. You run it through `filter_var` but you never check if the result is false.

Comment: So what is the difference between those two addresses? And what error message do you get?

Comment: Sounds like PHP doesn't know about the HTML address and crashes out. Try `$emailres = $_POST["trilogy_email"]`.

Comment: So you need validate the `$_POST["trilogy_email"]`. Are you sure, is that your name of your text field, and email is valid?

Comment: $emailres is the email address filled in the HTML form, if I set it manually to one particular address in PHP, it works. I just can't use the one that the user fills on the form.

Comment: The email address ($emailres) works just fine, I tried adding it to the message sent in PHP and it shows the one entered.
Just doesn't work while sending the email.

Comment: @KrupaKapadia When you enter your email in the form and submit it, what does `var_dump($emailres)` output?

Comment: @h2ooooooo it outputs, string(23) "krupakapdia93@gmail.com"
Which the email address I filled the form with.

Comment: PHPMailer also validates addresses when you call `AddAddress`, so check the return value there too. You should check the return value for `send()` as well, and for debugging you should try `SMTPDebug = 2`. You don't need to load the class as well as the autoloader - the autoloader is there to do that for you.

Comment: @Synchro, I changed the SMTP settings to that of Gmails, and tried sending an email from my gmail account, to the one entered in the form. Said email was invalid. I removed the filter_var, and left it to trim and somehow it works now.